# position title of UINavigationBar to be at the center horizentally and vertically

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have hard time to find how to do this simple thing on internet so I ask here.

I have a `UINavigationController`, which contains a `UINavigationBar`. By default if my app goes to 2nd embedded `UIViewController` the navigation bar shows a back button and a title. **But the title is not positioned in the center horizentally**.

How to make the title of `UINavigationBar` to be positioned always at the center horizentally & vertically?

[image]

What I meant is how to make the "Paid invoices" next to back button to be at the center of navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

It is default behaviour when you are pushing `ViewController` with `UINavigationController` it will show the title of previous screen  with back button

However, You can modify back button title with

`self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = ""`

and 
set title  like `self.title = "Paid invoices""`

it will show your title in center

Or you want to put custom back button image  then

call it from `ViewDidLoad`  of pushed view controller

```
func setBackButtonWithArrow() {
   self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(UIBarButtonItem.init(image: UIImage.init(named: "back_nav_White_arrow"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(popVC)), animated: true)
 }

func popVC () {
   self.navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
 }
```